# IIS Live Smooth Streaming: How to hide control bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, silverlight

Is it possible through some client-side scripting to hide the control bar in a Silverlight web player?

[image]

If so, how?

This is the SLplayer I'm using: http://jsfiddle.net/W5h6g/

I've tried placing **autohide=true** in the "initparams" value, but that didn't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<style type="text/css">
#silverlight {
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<object id="silverlight" data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2">
<param name="source" value="http://clubace.dk/bb.xap">
<param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError">
<param name="background" value="white">
<param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="4.0.50401.0">
<param name="autoUpgrade" value="true">
<param name="windowless" value="false">
<param name="InitParams" value="mediaurl=http://level3-live-smooth.cmore.se/live/1270108.isml/manifest">
</object>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:** *Question title changed and image added to clarify issue.*

Answer (score 1):

You can communicate to the Silverlight app from JavaScript, assuming you can change the source code for the Silverlight. So basically call a method inside Silverlight, from JavaScript and let the method (inside Silverlight) handle the removing of user control.

If you just want to remove the whole Silverlight object, you can simply hide/remove the div/object that holds the Silverlight content from JavaScript.

[Calling managed code (Silverlight) from JavaScript.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221414%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: I'm glad to hear that it's possible to influence the Silverlight through JavaScript :-) I also found this discussion on a similar topic [http://slvideoplayer.codeplex.com/discussions/208231](http://slvideoplayer.codeplex.com/discussions/208231). This shows that if I'm able to locate the attribute name in the xaml file of the Silverlight application which identifies the visible player controls, setting it's visibility to collapsed should hide the controls. However, I'm not really sure how to locate that attribute name in the xaml file.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to remove some user controls of your SL app from outside of it?

Comment: No, basically I need to remove or hide the entire control bar at the bottom of the SL player which is inside the app.
I've tried looking at the bb.xap file to figure out what .dll file needs to be edited to accomplish this. However, I'm totally new to this sort of thing so I'm kinda hoping that it can be done through javascript or something :-)